# R' Akiva visiting Syracuse

Tags: sources-mekorot, geography, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, italy

I have read a claim on [various](http://www.pjvoice.com/v33/33004sicily.aspx) [sites](https://www.jpost.com/diaspora/article-746346), including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Sicily#Ancient_history), that R' Akiva visited the city of Syracuse in current Sicily. However, I have failed to find its source in the Talmud. I have seen the [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66711/15256) about *Greek Italy* on [Megillah 6b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.6b.11), most probably referring to Syracuse, but I haven't found any mention of R' Akiva there. Could you please help me finding the source of this statement?

Comment: Maybe פרנדיסן / eruvin 4:1

Comment: @sam That's generally identified (such as by the *'Aruch*) as Brindisi, a city in southern Italy on the Adriatic coast.

Comment: I wouldn't say generally, since many peirushim just explain it as "name of a place" ,Medinas hayam...

Comment: Brindisi and Pulia (and apparently  Syracuse) were stops mentioned is a diary by Rabbi Akiva. I don't know what manuscript this is, but it is mentioned here. https://jguideeurope.org/en/region/italy/puglia/         https://www.j-italy.org/libraries/judaism-in-puglia-as-a-metaphor-for-mediterranean-judaism/      https://jguideeurope.org/en/type-de-lieu/region/

Comment: Here is the page from Eruvin: https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.41b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: @YaacovDeane Syracuse is in Sicily, whereas Brindisi mentioned in the Mishnah is in Puglia. I haven't seen on any of the pages you linked the name Syracuse.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I understand. Brindisi is close by geographically on the Adriatic Sea, but not actually Syracuse. One of the possibilities is that the place name is different in Shas. That Syracuse is called “Siriaze” by the locals of Calabria, for example. That place name can be found in Shas, not in connection with Akiva. I reached out to an Italian-Jewish published scholar who also mentions this Akiva/Syracuse connection. He has responded & said he will need to go through his own notes to see where he saw this. His memory was also Shas. But he used an unusual term about Akiva.

Comment: @Kazibácsi cont. He thought the reference was to ראש לחכמים, which is correct but unusual. Usually Rabbi Akiva is referenced as עקיבא בן יוסף or ר״ע. I searched for the alternate expression, also with no success. This makes me wonder if it was simply an oral tradition from the Jews of Calabria. I will, bli neder, keep you updated as I hear more. FYI, Siriaze is סריאז in Hebrew letters.

Comment: @Kazibácsi See for example, Seder HaDorot on Rabbi Avraham Taryaves of Syracuse.  ר׳ אברהם טרווש בסיראז, or רבי אברהם טריווש בסריאז.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I've reached out to an Italian chief rabbi, let's see how it goes! 

Comment: @Kazibácsi Shavuah tov! Please keep me apprised of whatever you find. Only blessings my friend!